# Inserting HTML to iframe works in Firefox/Chrome/Opera but not in IE7/8

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code bellow loads a HTML from an external page and inserts it into an iframe. It does not work in IE though (the IE completely freezes):

```
$.ajax({
    url: uri,
    success: function(response) {
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        div.html(iframe);
        var doc = iframe.document;
        if (iframe.contentDocument) {
            doc = iframe.contentDocument; // For NS6
        } else if(iframe.contentWindow) {
            doc = iframe.contentWindow.document; // For IE5.5 and IE6
        }
        doc.open();
        doc.writeln(response);
        doc.close();
    },
    error: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just: `div.html('<iframe src="' + uri + '"></iframe>')`? You need the error callback?

Comment: No I need to show loading animation before the iframe appears and with src attribute it's not possible. So I am trying to load the html with ajax and then insert it into iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I'd let jQuery handle the heavy lifting, since you're already using it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: uri,
    success: function(response) {
        var iframe = $('<iframe/>');
        div.html(iframe);
        iframe.contents().find('body').html(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah. Throw jQuery at it. That way you don't have to think or learn.

Comment: @Rob That's not what I said at all. jQuery is *already* being used. Abstracting these issues away is exactly what the library is for. It's best to use it.

Comment: That assumes that the response is not a full HTML document, which it probably is. You wouldn't want to load an entire document into the BODY element.